# Chrome changing background image position

Tags: css, google-chrome

I came across a strange behaviour with Chrome earlier that I can't seem to fix.

I have an image applied to `<body>` that is positioned: left top. While loading in Chrome the background positions as expected repeating on x from left top. Once the window is loaded, a class is added to the body tag: `backgroundPositionTuned` and an inline style that overwrites my own CSS `background-position: 0% 34px;`

This style as expected from the declaration shifts the image that should sit flush with the top of the page down by 36px on the y axis.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour and know how to counteract it?

The styling works fine in
IE 7,8,9
Firefox 9 >

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a relevant part of your code is a good idea...

Comment: You're right Alexander, I will update with a fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem on several pages (I mean not just on a page I developed, but also on several other). Accidentally I discover that if I disable the Chrome plugin uTorrentControl v2 (or something similar) and the problem disappear.
Cheers!

Comment: Same problem and fix with "Ask Toolbar extension"

Comment: Worked here as well. Deleted the extension!