# google chrome writing itself inline style in body tag

Tags: google-chrome

this is the site: www.luckybabynames.in

This site background is perfectly coming in both firefox and internet explorer. But the problem is now with google chrome.

Here is the css for the body background

```
body {
background: url("images/img01.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
color: #333333;
font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: justify;   }
```

no inline style written in body Tag

But in google chrome after the page fully loads it writing itself some inline style in the body tag.

```
<body style="postion: absolute; width: 1583px; height: 449px; background-position-x: 0px; background-position-y: 34px !important; " class="backgroundPositionTuned">
```

But actually there is no style and even the class="backgroundPostionTuned"!

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This previous question suggests that this behavior may be caused by the uTorrentControl extension:

[Chrome changing background image position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889776/chrome-changing-background-image-position)

Comment: As you said i removed the utorrent extension. It solved the problem in my browser but how can we prevent this for everyone?. Any Solution?

Comment: You can't. The extension is inherently flawed, and will mess with a lot of web sites.